# How to use cURL to send an XML file to a telnet server

Tags: ruby, curl, telnet

I am having trouble sending large data to a socket that I have listening on.

---

This is server.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'socket'

server = TCPServer::new 3000
loop do
  client = server.accept
  client.puts 'Running...'
  raw_data = client.gets.chomp
  client.puts "Got #{raw_data}"
  client.puts 'done.'
  client.close
end
```

---

After running the server using `$ ruby server.rb`, I am able to do

```
$ echo "test" | curl telnet://127.0.0.1:3000
Running...
Got test
done.

$ echo "something else" | curl telnet://127.0.0.1:3000
Running...
Got something else
done.
```

But I get an error when running this:

```
$ cat /a/sizable/xml/file.xml | curl telnet://127.0.0.1:3000
curl: (55) Send failure: Broken pipe
Running...%
```

It seems I can run it fine with a 43b file, but fails when I run it with a 5.3k XML file.

I've also tried:

```
$ curl -T "/a/sizable/xml/file.xml" telnet://localhost:3000
```

which yields the same result.

How can I send this raw XML data to my server?

Comment: Why use Telnet? Why not use a simple HTTP server? Writing something in Sinatra is trivial and sending data, either as XML or JSON to that server is very easy using any Ruby HTTP client.

Comment: absolutely, however i am going to put this into a docker container.  sinatra is a dependency i shouldn't need. "why not use a simple http server?" I am - that's what the `TCPServer` ruby class accomplishes

Comment: TCPServer helps, but isn't going to handle all the situations that a simple HTTP server will.

Comment: my sole situation, is sending raw xml content to the tcp server, that's it.  it should be able to handle that, correct?

Comment: i've removed the vernacular of "upload", since that's typically associated with HTTP servers.  I'm just trying to send.  that may have caused confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server, you are just reading the first line of data sent by the client

```
raw_data = client.gets.chomp
```

Your XML file probably contains multiple lines. However, after the first line was read by the server, it prints it back and simply closes the connection. This results in the "broken pipe" error you see as curl terminates with the closed connection.

In order to read the whole input, you can use this instead:

```
while raw_line = client.gets.chomp # Read lines from socket
  client.puts "Got #{raw_line}"    # and print them
end
client.puts "done."
```

Comment: well - that did it.. thank you very much!  didn't expect `gets` to return just a line, though i suppose it makes sense in ruby terms :)